# How physical are vacuum solutions to Einstein's equations?

Tags: general-relativity

It is shown in any standard textbook on general relativity how you might get black holes and gravitational radiation, both of which are vacuum solutions to field equations, i.e., such that energy-momentum tensor (EMT) is set to zero. My questions is how justified setting EMT to zero in a real physical situation? Well, we all know that even physical vacuum alone is not nothingness, so it might be characterized by an appropriate EMT. Besides there is the ubiquitous dark energy (if that't actually not the vacuum) and dark matter, neutrino radiation, CMB, and traces of baryonic matter. I guess the answer here is "of course, there is no ideal vacuum anywhere, but in this situation we might simply neglect the EMT". But my concern is how to quantify the criterion when we might neglect any matter/radiation (after all, when we search for Friedman equations, we do not set EMT to zero at later epochs of the Universe evolution, even though the energy density is very low). Another concern is that field equations are notoriously non-linear. Couldn't it be that when you have a solution with non-zero EMT, and then tend EMT to zero, they do not simply converge to a vacuum solution?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we start with the Schwarzchild vacuum solution and want to know how the presence of dark energy changes it. Assuming dark energy can reasonably be described by a cosmological constant, we can describe our black hole using the [Schwarzschild-de Sitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric) metric. If you want instead to see what would happen in the presence of matter we could use the [Vaidya metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaidya_metric).

Admittedly, these are very simplified representations of the real world, but the fact they exist and are not radically different from the Schwarzschild solution suggests that the vacuum solutions are a good initial approximation for real black holes.